# Seamos cuidadosos con los comentarios y/o sugerencias hacia las preguntas de otros usuarios

Tags: discusión

Me he fijado en algunas preguntas que por 'x' razón no están muy bien formuladas, eso no es el tema, el tema es que existen usuarios 'nuevos' que aportan comentarios sugiriendo que corrijan la pregunta, etc., eso está muy bien, que bueno que quieran ayudar a mejorar la comunidad, el detalle es que tenemos que tener cuidado con la ortografía ya que sería contradictorio corregir a alguien si también estamos mal xD.

> "Bienvenida a SOesp. Éste es el sitio Stack Overflow en español. Has de
>   editar tu pregunta y dejarla en español o será cerrada. También has de
>   especificar más: poner algo de codigo que tengas, cosas que has
>   intentado/descartado, ... etc"

Espero no se lo tomen a mal solo que es algo que vi y quise hacer una sugerencia.
Este es la [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/28985/jfreechart-into-jsplitpanel-using-netbeans) con el comentario.

Comment: Vaya, voy a tener que borrar todos mis comentarios :) Es que me toma una eternidad poner los acentos con mi teclado en inglés...

Comment: @sstan A mi me ha pasado que me doy cuenta del error y ya no puedo editarlo porque han pasado 5 minutos :P

Comment: @devconcept puedes re redactar el comentario en uno nuevo y eliminar el anterior.

Comment: Je, si, siempre y cuando no tengas varios comentarios posteriores al tuyo porque sino sería imposible leer la conversación :P

Comment: De todos modos, los revisores, yo y otros cerramos la pregunta... En caso de que en el futuro esté en el idioma correcto será abierta.

Answer (score 5):

Buenas!

hahaha esa frase de tu ejemplo la puse yo ^^' .

No estoy corrigiendo su ortografía, si no diciéndole que no es el idioma apropiado. Respecto a mi mensaje, veo que falta una tilde en "codigo", algo más que me haya dejado?

La verdad es que me preocupo bien poco por como escribo en español. Ya que es aquí donde únicamente hablo en español en Internet. Pero si escribo un comentario del tipo que tú mencionas, ahí si me esfuerzo. Pero nadie es perfecto.

Comment: No lo tomes tan a pecho, solo es una sugerencia, pero me refiero a que suena contradictorio, es como si yo te dijera que estás mal en esta respuesta... komentando de ezta  forma ¯\_(ツ)_/¯, ojo, solo es sugerencia, saludos :)

Comment: Pero no me lo tomo de ninguna manera. Solo pregunto que está mal de mi comentario ya que solo veo una tilde que falta

Comment: Y sobra otra en "Este". Por lo demás no veo que ese comentario se pueda poner de ejemplo de mala ortografía, son errores menores de acentos.

Comment: @lois6b Me confundía yo, pensaba que no era pronombre, pero sí. Entonces solo te falta el acento en código :)

Comment: @blonfu estabas en lo correcto a la tilde http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18538/cu%C3%A1ndo-se-debe-acentuar-el-pronombre-este/18539

Comment: Bien, me parecía raro ese acento pero estaba equivocado en la razón de no usarlo. Es bueno saberlo para la próxima vez que tenga esa duda

Comment: Gracias a esta pregunta/respuesta en [spanish.se] incorporamos a @blonfu, ¡gran usuario con muy buenas publicaciones!

Comment: @fedorqui si hahaha ya lo hablamos por el chat. un buen fichaje este blonfu xD

Comment: Gracias @fedorqui y lois6b por la parte que me toca. Cierto, descubrí Spanish Language por los comentarios que intercambiamos en esta pregunta  lois6b y yo, o yo y lois6b (que ahora sabemos que está bien el yo delante también)