# Faltas de ortografía

Tags: discusión, idioma-español

Estaría bien que en SOes hubiera un lugar destacado donde los usuarios pudieran ver la forma de escribir correctamente. O que aparecieran tips en el momento en que se está escribiendo la pregunta. Por ejemplo:

> "Interrogantes al principio y al final ¿?", "
>   Cómo se escribe con acento, (si es pregunta)" y cosas por el estilo.

En general la gente escribe bastante mal y unos pequeños consejos en formato tip cortito estaría genial.

Comment: ¿En serio? Lo entendería si fuese un sitio donde la gente no conoce el idioma pero lo normal es que el idioma de quien viene a preguntar aquí sea el español, de otra forma es más probable que vaya  directamente a SO y pregunte en inglés. Ya me parece bastante increible que tengamos que estar continuamente explicando a la gente como preguntar, no que tipo de preguntas son aceptadas (que es normal no saber al principio) sino como redactar una pregunta. Tener que recordar normas ortográficas me parece demasiado.

Comment: Tu propuesta es muy loable pero si fuera por mi lo descartaría, claro que no coincido muchas veces con el criterio de la mayoría ;)

Comment: Relacionados: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/286/227 http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/945/227

Comment: Creo que es algo importante pues ayuda a comprender mejor las preguntas. He corregido hace un par de días una pregunta que tenía cada 4 o 5 palabras una coma. Y otras cosillas que no ayudaban a ser bien comprendida. Por lo que creo que pequeños tips sobre ortografía podrían ser interesantes. Obviamente aquí solo se habla de programación y lo que comento no es necesario. Pero a veces hay gente que pone un s en lugar de una c y hace que no se entienda la pregunta.

Comment: Opino que somos una comunidad, no un gobierno, menos un gobierno totalitario. Ortografía es importante, porque mejora la comunicación y la claridad, sin embargo no hay nada mal con simplemente ayudar a la gente con eso sin funarlos.

No hay que olvidar que no todos los usuarios crecieron con español o castellano, yo por ejemplo aprendí castellano desde que vivo en chile, y no creo que mis aportes en la informatica sean menores porque no escribo como Neruda o Becker.

Entonces corrigijo un "haber" si se trata de un "a ver", pero no me pongo fanatico tampoco. Todo es más fácil en equipo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tal y como [comenta blonfu](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1091/faltas-de-ortograf%C3%ADa#comment2680_1091):

> tener que recordar normas ortográficas me parece demasiado

Ahora bien, también es cierto que a todos [nos surgen dudas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1159/lleg%C3%B3-diciembre-2016-cu%C3%A1ndo-iniciar%C3%A1-el-winter-bash#comment2942_1159) ortográficas o gramáticales. ¡Eso es bueno! Y mejor aún es saber que existe un sitio específico para este tipo de dudas y [ya hay quien lo usa](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/945/seamos-cuidadosos-con-los-comentarios-y-o-sugerencias-hacia-las-preguntas-de-otr/947?noredirect=1#comment2294_947). Se trata de...

## [Spanish Language Stack Exchange](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/)

Así que si tenéis dudas, no dudéis en entrar allí para comentarlas. Tras más de cinco años en beta y unas 3700 preguntas (y más de 10.000 respuestas) tenemos una base de datos bastante grande para que muchas de vuestras dudas se vean resueltas con una simple búsqueda.

Por ejemplo, disponemos de la [etiqueta *informática*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inform%C3%A1tica) con multitud de preguntas del tipo:

- [¿Hay alguna forma de traducir al español “commit”, hablando de bases de datos?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17811/1674)
- [¿Hay una traducción aceptada para “pretty print”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16081/1674)
- [¿“Binding” en castellano?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15534/1674)
- [How would you translate “Dashboard” from a web application point of view?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13445/1674)