# Llegó diciembre 2016, ¿cuándo iniciará el Winter Bash?

Tags: discusión, winterbash-2016

¿Habrá sombreros secretos este año 2016? ¿Tendremos "Winter Bash" en Stack Overflow en español?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego unos enlaces ([1](http://stackoverflow.blog/2015/12/announcing-winter-bash-2015/), [2](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/01/Winter-Bash-2015-Hats-Off/)) con información para los que aún no hayan participado.

Comment: Sí! Pronto habrá una publicación al respecto. :)

Comment: Bueno, me voy yendo a cortar el pelo.. XD

Comment: ¿Que es eso realmente? ¿Es una característica de aquí solamente? No la he visto nunca en SOen.

Comment: @Error404 agregué unos link donde hay información!

Comment: @Elenasys Muchas gracias por el link. Suena raro y divertido a la vez. ¡Habrá que probarlo!

Comment: Es raro verte en Meta @Elenasys ... Ah y espero haya de charros  :>

Comment: Que bueno!!! Yo quiero alguno!! Gracias @Elenasys!!!

Comment: @Elenasys siento si [mi revisión](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/posts/1159/revisions) usando _comenzar_ en lugar de _iniciar_ no te gustó. Me suena rarísimo usar _iniciar_ en este contexto.

Comment: @fedorqui Ohhh una disculpa, pensé yo había agregado ese texto!!! por eso lo cambié. Pensaba era más común iniciar que comenzar! lo siento!

Comment: Faltaría más, Elenasys. De hecho me generó la duda y [acabo de preguntarlo](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19047/1674) en [spanish.se] jaja.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

El Winter Bash (hemisferio norte) / Sumter Bash (hemisferio sur) comenzará el 19 de diciembre y continuará hasta el 8 de enero del año entrante.  Para más información sobre este evento, por favor lean aquí: [Presentamos Winter Bash 2015](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256/presentamos-winter-bash-2015)

Después de nuestra graduación (tendremos una en 2017) los moderadores del sitio publicarán aquí en el Meta para preguntarles a ustedes si les gustaría participar en este evento ese año.  Si se decide a favor, tendremos el evento.  Si no...pues se lo pueden imaginar.

¡Felices días de fiesta!

Comment: Podremos abrigarnos para pasar el verano ❄️. Firmado: el Hemisferio Sur!   ... (pd: no es crítica, sólo un poco de humor).

Comment: Podría ser un "WinMer" o "SumTer" bash...;)

Comment: Mientras tanto podéis disfrutar de una bonita cuenta atrás: http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com

Comment: Pegó el "*SumTer*"...tendría que haberlo registrado. ;). SumTer®