# ¿Qué cambia cuando el sitio pasa de beta a graduado?

Tags: discusión, graduación, fase-beta

En la publicación [Buenas noticias para mayo 2017](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/04/20/buenas-noticias-para-mayo-2017/), se explican los cambios en cuanto a privilegios por reputación. ¿Qué otras cosas cambian?

Comment: Pues me he esforzado en ser super neutral. Pero acepto sugerencias.

Comment: Tal vez preguntar por los cambios que vienen, y poner como ejemplo la expectativa en cuanto a los moderadores y la duda en cuanto al CM. Para que la pregunta fuera "exhaustivamente" completa, habría que incluir referencias a "todos" los artículos de ayuda e hilos relativos aunque no creo que a alguien le interesen las preguntas "exhaustivas" ya que cansan :P

Comment: Que bueno que cambió el título de la pregunta, porque el otro era muy, muy, muy, muy irrelevante. Ahora la pregunta es bastante útil.

Comment: @fedorqui ¿Cuál es la idea de la etiqueta fase-beta (no tiene guía de uso, esta es la única pregunta con dicha etiqueta)?

Comment: @Rubén igual que [meta-tag:graduación], la añadí para contextualizar la publicación y a imagen y semejanza de [meta.se]. Allí existe [`beta-phase`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beta-phase) y [`graduating-sites`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graduating-sites).

Comment: @fedorqui: Considero que hay mejores formas de agregar contexto que el usar etiquetas sin un resumen/wiki, considerando que en algunas partes de la documentación de ayuda se recomienda evitar crear nuevas etiquetas, por otro lado, hace tiempo leí que la creación de nuevos sitios en idiomas distintos al inglés estaba detenida por tiempo indefinido, así que no creo que se deba fomentar la publicación de preguntas con dichas etiquetas mientras no tengan un resumen/wiki. Por cierto, `graduating-sites` no tiene resumen/wiki

Comment: Nota: Se está reforzando en mí la idea de "protestar" la etiqueta `fase-beta`, al menos mientras no tenga orientación de uso/wiki, al contrario de [meta-tag:graduación] ya que esta última se está usando en  preguntas sobre las celebraciones de graduación del sitio y me parece que también podría usarse para cambios que nos gustaría ver u ocurran a raíz de la misma.

Comment: @Rubén [meta-tag:graduación] la creé ayer y luego JuanM la usó porque vino al caso. Creo que el nombre de ambas es suficientemente descriptivo, por lo que incluso sin resumen/wiki es útil (dudo que demasiada gente lea esas wikis, es un tema que está encallado desde hace tiempo). No entiendo tu referencia a la creación de nuevos sitios, ¿a qué aplica en este contexto?

Comment: @fedorqui en su momento que lo mencioné a que en [meta.se] se usan las etiquetas referidas para preguntar sobre otros sitios, no sobre [meta.se].

Comment: @Rubén https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/102 y https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/103

Comment: @fedorqui: Gracias por los enlaces. Voy a dejar reposar este tema en particular un rato

Comment: @Mariano Sí, se responde a la pregunta, estamos de acuerdo. Que me interesaban más las otras cosas aparte de los cambios en la reputación siempre ha sido así, salvo en la primera y breve versión. Es natural estar más interesado en lo que desconoces. Pero veo muy bien que lo incluyas en la respuesta para que sea completa.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Por mucho tiempo nos preguntamos qué condiciones eran necesarias para que SOes se gradúe, a veces sólo por el deseo de olvidarnos de ser "beta", a veces por querer que se apliquen los cambios en privilegios, y otras tantas para ver cómo mejorar la comunidad desde una visión constructiva, analizando qué factores se podían mejorar en comparación a otras comunidades (-sí, me incluyo en este último).

Antes que nada, aprovecho para felicitar a toda la comunidad por lo que está por venir. Es muy grato ver que los esfuerzos que fuimos haciendo para que SOes sea grande, pero no sólo en número sino en calidad sobre todo, van rindiendo frutos.

Somos, y cada vez queda más claro, una comunidad que pisa fuerte y de forma saludable, en la que SOes (cito a [Joel Spolsky](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/)):

> **Hace de la Internet un mejor lugar para obtener respuestas de expertos a tus preguntas.**

Parece que fue ayer cuando empezábamos con el sitio, y nos preguntábamos cómo iniciar, cómo hacer que el tráfico crezca, cómo comportarnos, qué preguntas se permitían, qué comportamientos estaban bien vistos... En fin, una gran cantidad de temas que fuimos superando, y muchos que aún estamos en proceso de hacerlo.

¿Vieron en dónde se ubica SOes [en cantidad de preguntas por día actualmente](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday)?

[image: SOes 8vo en toda la red]

- No sólo está 8vo en toda la red, y subiendo aceleradamente, codeándose con sitios que llevan muchos años activos.
- Es el beta de mayor cantidad de preguntas por día (-bueno, no por mucho tiempo).
- Se proyectan 150 preguntas por día para fin de año.

#### ¡Felicitaciones comunidad!

---

### ¿Y ahora?

Hace mucho tiempo, [se incluían en la graduación](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200383/304899):

- Crear un blog para el sitio... Ya está hecho!.
- Crear Avisos de Promoción de la Comunidad... Ya está hecho!

Pero vayamos a lo importante, está todo excelentemente expresado en la publicación de JuanM, [Buenas noticias para mayo 2017](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/04/20/buenas-noticias-para-mayo-2017/), por lo que vuelvo a incluir esta información.

#### Nuevos límites para los privilegios.

> Cuando un sitio esta en su fase beta, los privilegios que se permiten
>   son muchos comparados con los que se permiten cuando un sitio se
>   gradúa.  La razón de esto es para empoderar a los usuarios a poder
>   participar con más facilidad en el sitio. Les comparto la siguiente
>   tabla para mostrarles los cambios de puntuación que ocurrirán.

[image: Nuevos privilegios]
<sup>* corregí [algunos detalles](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1881/127) antes de publicar esta tabla</sup>

Para ver la lista completa, se pueden ver los [privilegios de Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/).

#### Elecciones para moderadores

Como en todos los sitios que se gradúan, la propia comunidad elige sus moderadores. El formato es el mismo que en toda la red, y podrás verlo una vez que se haya iniciado en https://es.stackoverflow.com/election

Los moderadores actuales son reemplazados (o reelectos). Ese es **el único cambio** en cuanto a los moderadores o cualquier otro administrador del sitio.

No obstante, ya llegará el anuncio oficial. Esperemos a que así sea.

#### Cambios en el diseño del sitio.

En muchas comunidades, se realizan cambios en el layout del sitio, adaptándolos a las características de cada uno. No obstante, es de esperar que SOes se mantenga coherente con el resto de los sitios SO* (Stack Overflow y todos los SO internacionales).

El anuncio reciente de Juan, puede ser considerado como parte de estos cambios:

[La navegación nueva se aplicará aquí muy pronto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1779/127)

#### Celebraciones

Vuelvo a citar a Juan en [Buenas noticias para mayo 2017](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/04/20/buenas-noticias-para-mayo-2017/).

> ¡Como me encantaría celebrar con todos ustedes este gran evento en
>   vivo!  Aunque me es imposible verlos a todos, estoy planeando dos
>   celebraciones para festejar – una en España y otra en México. ¡Ojo!
>   tal vez será en un lugar muy cercano de ti.

Por lo personal, estaré brindando desde acá!

Comment: ¿Lo de la navegación tiene que ver con el paso a graduarse? ¿Seguirá habiendo gestor de comunidad? ¿A cuantos moderadores se elegirá y quién decide cuantos? ¿Lo deciden todo los moderadores y la comunidad: temática, excepciones, etc? ¿O hay cosas que que no? Gracias por tu respuesta y +1.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Algunos sitios al graduarse cambian el layout (a veces un poco antes, a veces un poco después, a veces no lo cambian). En nuestro caso, ese es el cambio que se publicó. Podemos relacionarlo a la graduación o no... La elección de moderadores es el único cambio en cuanto a moderación o gestión, y no habrá cambios en CMs, desarrolladores, ni ningún otro empleado (si hubiese algún cambio, se anunciaría, pero no estaría relacionado a la graduación)...

Comment: Los moderadores los elige la comunidad votando, cuántos y más detalles se van a anunciar oficialmente en una publicación en meta... Esos son todos los cambios, cualquier otra cosa podría surgir desde una propuesta en Meta.

Comment: Pregunto, ¿hay medallas asociadas con los privilegios? ¿Si pierdo mis privilegios, perderé la medalla asociada, si existe? Estoy muy angustiado.

Comment: @toledano no hay ninguna medalla asociada a un privilegio. Además, ninguna medalla se puede perder, jamás, incluso cuando las condiciones para esa medalla ya no cumplan... Hay una sola medalla asociada a la graduación, pero sólo es para moderadores. Espero que pueda liberar tu angustia y puedas dormir tranquilo esta noche ;-)

Comment: De hecho sí hay medallas que se pueden perder: las medallas por etiquetas. Pero el resto no, una vez se consiguen son tuyas para siempre jamás.

Comment: @fedorqui Es cierto, gracias por recordármelo... Y aclaro que no está relacionado a la graduación, sino que se podrían perder si se restan votos en publicaciones de esa etiqueta, y se volverían a ganar con más votos.

Comment: **¡Viva SOes!**, ¡Viva los beta testers! (todos nosotros), ¡Viva los "Area 51 Committers"!, ¡Viva jachguate! quien realizó la propuesta,¡Viva JuanM! quien ha hecho mucho frente y tras bambalinas, ¡Viva los programadores! quienes agregaron i18n a la plataforma. Gracias Mariano por tu excelente publicación. Discrepo en que "todo" está bien explicado en la publicación sobre la graduación del sitio, no por criticar aquella, sino porque me parece que hay algunos elementos que discutir, elementos que en esta respuesta se mencionan, pero hay que darle tiempo al tiempo, tan sólo *de 2 a 6 semanas*.

Comment: @Victor-Random: Como ya lo [mencioné](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1884/65), pienso que está bien hacer la mención del error para que Mariano incluya una nota o realice otra acción al respecto, la fuente está en el artículo de blog que se indica como fuente, lo ideal es que el comentario se haga allá.

Comment: @Rubén tengo fuertes problemas con el internet por eso no podia modificar los comentarios/preguntas

Comment: @Victor-Random: Toma el tiempo que necesites.

Answer (score 2):

En la [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1813/65) de Mariano se menciona que en [Buenas noticias para mayo 2017](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/04/20/buenas-noticias-para-mayo-2017/) se explican los cambios. Desde mi punto de vista, la publicación no es exhaustiva, considero se han dejado de lado algunas cosas seguramente porque hacer cosas exhaustivas es "exhaustante", además de que está fuera de moda.

A continuación hago un compendio "abreviado" <sup>1</sup> de hilos en los que se menciona cosas que cambiarían cuando el sitio se gradúe:

- [Respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1800/65) a [Me gustaria que el CM o algun moderador determinara o creara un post](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1793/65)

  Con respecto a las publicaciones de agradecimiento:

  > En cuanto el sitio se gradúe, no se permitirán estas preguntas. Seguiremos lo indicado en [esta publicación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1624/c%C3%B3mo-dar-las-gracias-a-los-usuarios-que-responden-a-mis-preguntas) la cual contiene la posición oficial de nuestra red.
- [Respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1160/65) a [Llegó diciembre 2016, ¿cuándo iniciará el Winter Bash?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1159/65)

  > Después de nuestra graduación (tendremos una en 2017) los moderadores del sitio publicarán aquí en el Meta para preguntarles a ustedes si les gustaría participar en este evento ese año. Si se decide a favor, tendremos el evento. Si no...pues se lo pueden imaginar.

En resumen, además de lo ya anunciado, me parece que podemos esperar que haya más cosas que están o que en futuro se agreguen a SO (en inglés), como las etiquetas patrocinadas, y algunas "reglas" se aplicarán con mayor rigor, tanto por el CM, como por los moderadores (diamantados o no).

<sup>1</sup> Si es compendio, es breve; bueno, pues este, es aún más breve.