# Error en la tabla de cambios de reputación para obtener privilegios y en mensaje de felicitaciones

Tags: discusión, meta, privilegios

Estuve leyendo la publicación [¿Qué cambia cuando el sitio pasa de beta a graduado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1813/) y encontré que en la tabla (imagen) dice que para editar publicaciones en el beta publico se requieren **750 puntos de reputacion**.

Justo hoy he conseguido **1000 puntos de reputación** y he obtenido el privilegio:

> ¡Has ganado un nuevo privilegio!
>
> Gracias a tus esfuerzos, puedes
>
> Editar preguntas y respuestas

Hay un error de redacción, ya que en realidad fueron **1000 puntos de reputación** los que tuve que reunir.

Además de que dice "*Editar publicaciones*" y en las felicitaciones te dice "*Editar preguntas y respuestas*".

Por otro lado en el privilegio de "votos para cerrar" sale escrito "votos para cerra".

Cito a **Spencer** del programa **Icarly**: "La elegancia ante todo", Es algo sencillo pero la calidad se basa en los pequeños detalles.

Comment: Eso es una foto. Mira la [tabla oficial de privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: "editar publicaciones" y "editar preguntas y respuestas" en los sitios de Stack Exchange son equivalentes.

Comment: @fedorqui, si lees la pregunta veras que lo especifico, se encuentra en la **tabla**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es correcta tu apreciación, son dos pequeños errores en la publicación del blog.

Edité la respuesta a [¿Qué cambia cuando el sitio pasa de beta a graduado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1810/127), por lo que ya aparecen los textos correctos.

---

Como [mencionó Rubén](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1884/127), es más práctico comentar debajo de la publicación. Incluso, en este caso, hubiese recomendado una edición directa en la respuesta por parte de cualquiera que quisiera corregirlo.

Comment: Yo lo publique en el blog, pero como antes no habia podido borrar preguntas con respuestas , no pense en borrar esto ejejje

Answer (score 3):

El error no está en el sistema, sino en una publicación, por lo que no creo que [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) sea la apropiada en este caso. El [artículo de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) sobre el privilegio coincide con el mensaje.

Por otro lado, las críticas a publicaciones en Meta o el sitio principal deben realizarse en publicaciones usando comentarios, sin embargo, considerando que la publicación original de la tabla fue [en el blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/04/20/buenas-noticias-para-mayo-2017/) y que este incluye la opción de publicar comentarios, ahí mismo se debería hacer la observación. En la [publicación referida](http://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1810/qu%C3%A9-cambia-cuando-el-sitio-pasa-de-beta-a-graduado/1813#1813) en esta pregunta, se podría hacer mención del error, y lo ideal sería que el autor de la publicación lo agregara.

Sí, ya se que esta es una crítica y para ser coherente debería publicarlo como comentario de la pregunta, pero en este caso, considero que esta crítica en sí es la respuesta.

Comment: me pedia una etiqueta adicional y me parecio que entre discusion y bug, era un bug. ya lo corregi, no pense en soporte porque creo que seria algo mas complejo

Comment: me sugieres entonces que publique esto como comentario o que deje el anterior que me has comentando?

Comment: @Victor-Random. Mi sugerencia principal es que vayas a la fuente donde está el origen del error y lo comentes ahí.

Comment: Listo gracias :)

Comment: Ya fue corregido en la publicación en meta.