# ¿Quién decide el mínimo de puntos de reputación para tal o cual privilegio y cuál es el procedimiento para hacerlo?

Tags: discusión, privilegios

A raíz de todas las discusiones en Meta de la cantidad y calidad de moderación actualmente en el sitio (las cuales creo que mejoraran con el tiempo, sin duda) me vino esta pregunta a la mente. Trate de buscar en el Centro de Ayuda pero no encontré nada.

Creo importante mencionar que, mi pregunta es en general y no solo en la parte de moderación.

Si la respuesta fuera que esto está a cargo de la comunidad (como presiento que será) sería bueno analizar si bajar los limites (y en consecuencia tener más personas con acceso a la colas) supondría una mejora en la moderación del sitio.

Y todo esto viene porque, pienso que debería existir un balance. Es cierto que aquí no votamos mucho, pero eso no debería ser un obstáculo para mantener la calidad del sitio, hablando en referencia a la moderación y en otros apartados también. Quizás, si no es un procedimiento tan complicado, podemos ajustar los limites para que sean adecuados al comportamiento actual de la comunidad y mientras vayamos observando cambios ajustarlo hasta que llegue al nivel actual.

Comment: Puede estar relacionado con [La cola de revisión de preguntas a cerrar siempre tiene muchas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3243/la-cola-de-revisi%c3%b3n-de-preguntas-a-cerrar-siempre-tiene-muchas)

Comment: @KacosPro esta, de hecho. Pero estoy mas intrigado en saber quien esta a cargo y cual es el procedimiento, antes de dar una sugerencia de ese tipo, que al parecer (por los votos) fue descabellada.

Comment: Me parece muy muy muy bueno que traigas esto a discusión. Agregaría también el opuesto para que esté todo en la balanza: antes de que el sitio [se graduara](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1810/127), los privilegios eran mucho más bajos (como cualquier beta) y existían muchísimos problemas justamente por eso -usuarios que sin la experiencia suficiente en cómo funciona el sitio y cómo se modera realizaban algunas acciones no del todo informadas con un impacto significativo.

Comment: Yo personalmente estoy en contra de bajar al reputación necesaria para privilegios de moderación. Considero el proceso de moderación muy importante, y creo que necesitamos usuarios con experiencia suficiente. Como bien dice @Mariano, tenemos la experiencia de antes de la graduación. Mientras no haya mas usuarios con esos privilegios, los que si les tenemos tendremos que hacer un esfuerzo extra...

Comment: @Pikoh pues tienes un punto valido. Como dije, yo realmente quisiera sacar conclusiones claras de todo esto. Otra opcion seria subir la reputacion, no crees? Quizas las personas que tienen los privilegios no se lo toman tan importante como deberia ser, o quizas, especificamente para las colas de revision, el proceso pueda ser diferente, y no se necesite reputacion para acceder, sino aprobacion de los moderadores (despues de algun tiempo de prueba). Creeme que lo que menos quiero es recargar a los que si tienen estos privilegios.

Comment: Yo ya llevo tiempo abogando por que la forma de subir la reputación y el número de usuarios con privilegios en las colas de moderación es **votar**. Votar mucho. Creo que alguien (@mariano?) ya hizo un estudio de que [es.so] es de los sitios de Stack Exchange donde menos se vota. Y eso debemos cambiarlo entre todos.

Comment: La 3ra métrica en [Métricas interesantes para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2000/127) @Pikoh ;-)

Comment: Sabía que saldrías al rescate @Mariano :)

Comment: @Pikoh hace mucho vemos que no se vota. Algunos creen, erróneamente, que los votos son para publicaciones "*excelentes*", cuando no es así (para eso son los favoritos). En esa misma publicación, creo que sería bueno que cada uno se compare con el resto y vea si debería bajar sus requisitos. Se puede comparar en **[esta tabla](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/670814/votos-de-usuarios-de-mayor-reputacion?TOP=1000&ActivoHace=30&RepMin=1000&RepMax=0&PostsMin=0&VotosMin=0&UVMin=0&DVMin=0&VRepMin=0&VRepMax=0&VdayMin=0&VdayMax=0#resultSets)** -conviene ordenar por `%Votos/Reputación` o similar.

Comment: Como siempre, muy interesante @Mariano. Y, como imaginaba, veo que yo soy el primero que debo mentalizarme de votar mucho mas. Es cierto que yo solo estoy atento a unos tags específicos, con lo que mi campo de acción es mas reducido, pero aun asi me comprometo a aumentar mi ratio de votos. A ver si poco a poco intentamos todos aumentar estas estadísticas :)

Comment: @Pikoh creo que es algo que *todos* tenemos que mejorar continuamente (siempre hay algo para mejorar y lo de los votos es más notorio por ahora). Hay casos mucho más llamativos que el tuyo, pero al fin y al cabo cada uno vos lo que quiere, eso es mucho más importante que cualquier métrica. Lo que intento siempre es dar herramientas para que cada uno evalúe si tiene claro *qué significa un voto* (no es para "*algo maravilloso*", sino para algo "*que es útil, que está más o menos bien*").

Answer (score 5):

Los requisitos de reputación para un privilegio pueden ser ajustados por la comunidad teniendo, claro, el visto bueno de [CMs](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1670/127).

En *[Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/304899)* se mencionan algunas diferencias en privilegios entre sitios. Ejemplos:

- SO [crear etiquetas](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) (1500),
- Math [crear etiquetas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) (1000),
- StackApps [crear etiquetas](https://stackapps.com/help/privileges/create-tags) (99),
- MSE [crear etiquetas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) (500),
- MSE [voto en contra](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) (100),
- Mathoverflow [meta](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) (1)

Una propuesta debería surgir desde MSOes, estar muy bien justificada y tener el aval de la comunidad para empezar. En Math por ejemplo, se modificó el requisito para crear etiquetas en el 2014 con la publicación: *[Should rep requirements for tag creation be higher?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12359)*. En MSE se modificó la reputación requerida para votar en contra en el 2016 con *[Change rep required to downvote on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273000/304899)*.

> Quizás, si no es un procedimiento tan complicado, podemos ajustar los limites para que sean adecuados al comportamiento actual de la comunidad y mientras vayamos observando cambios ajustarlo hasta que llegue al nivel actual.

Tampoco me atrevería a calificarlo como algo sencillo, al contrario. No por una dificultad técnica, sino por las implicancias. Sobre todo porque creo que deberían cumplirse algunos puntos antes de proponer.

Esto es solamente lo que me parece, no está estipulado en ningún lado, puedo equivocarme:

1. ¿Es una propuesta que realmente justifica, sin lugar a dudas, que le conviene al sitio, separándose de lo que se adoptó en toda la red tras años de experiencia y una enorme cantidad de casos de estudio?
2. ¿Se agotaron todas los esfuerzos posibles para mejorar la situación problemática antes de intentar cambiar el modelo?
3. ¿Se analizó en profundidad, no solamente los pros, sino también los contras de la propuesta y a qué parte de la comunidad afecta y cómo?
4. ¿Se evaluó la historia del sitio, los problemas que se discutieron en Meta y cómo hubiese impactado un requisito diferente en ese privilegio?
5. ¿Cómo empezaría a coexistir ese cambio en el privilegio con el resto de los privilegios?

> sería bueno analizar si bajar los límites (y en consecuencia tener más personas con acceso a la colas) supondría una mejora en la moderación del sitio.

Como te comenté apenas la leí, me parece una pregunta excelente. Estás por traer a discusión un tema muy interesante que vale la pena analizar. Además, está más que claro que surge como un intento de resolver un problema actual en el sitio -eso está genial.

No quiero coartar la discusión de ningún modo que, sea cual fuera, me encantaría que suceda, pero creo que es un buen momento para adelantarte muy brevemente algunos argumentos en contra:
<sub>*(aviso: -en principio no me cierra la idea de reducir en cola de cierre, veré los argumentos)</sub>

- Lecciones aprendidas. Antes de [la graduación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1810/127), los privilegios eran más bajos, como en cualquier beta. Se daban muchísimos problemas, especialmente con cierres prematuros o no del todo bien informados. Te recomiendo leer lo que se publicó en Meta.
- Ludificación. La reputación y la ludificación de ésta es un motor importante en el crecimiento de un sitio. Bajar un privilegio juega en contra de este incentivo.
- Situación actual. No solamente faltan revisores (como en cualquier sitio graduado no hace mucho) también hay que mejorar los criterios de cierre. Un límite menor suma a usuarios con menos experiencia.
- Dinámica. Mencionaste la idea de ir modificando acorde se vaya avanzando. Es un punto interesante, pero me imagino que en cada punto habrá opiniones a favor y en contra, generando bastante discusión, y no creo que sea algo que se pueda definir tan a la ligera como para ir acompañando el crecimiento continuamente.

Pero no quiero tampoco centrarme en esto. La cola de cierre no es lo único que podemos analizar, hay mucho para sacarle jugo.

Comment: Mariano, gracias por tu repuesta, es muy buena. La verdad me asombra que no hayan mas personas en esta discusion. Pues eso, de alli que esto sea una discusion. Le mencionaba a Pikoh mas arriba, que quizas decrementar la cantidad de reputacion no sea la solucion, sino subirla. O quizas otro proceso, como una eleccion de parte de los moderadores. De cualquier forma, yo creo que la calidad y cantidad de revisiones va a mejorar con el tiempo. Solo me gustaria saber que piensan todos de esto, pero al parecer estan un poco timidos por el momento.

Comment: @KennyBarrera hasta donde entendí, si bien la pregunta insinuaba una propuesta para modificar algo, en realidad estás preguntando "*quien decide*" (yo simplemente adelanté algunos argumentos)... Pero creo que esto es solamente el paso previo... Me imaginaba que después de esta respuesta ibas a publicar **otra** pregunta sugiriendo algo concreto, donde el resto pueda opinar.

Comment: Es cierto, tienes razon. Es solo que es dificil proponer algo por mi cuenta, en parte porque aun no tengo todos los privilegios (mas que todo porque no puedo estar todo el tiempo que quisiera por aca) y porque las colas de primeras publicaciones y respuestas tardias nunca estan demasiado llenas. En fin, volviendo al tema, creo que mi pregunta ha sido contestada, eso es bueno.

Answer (score 3):

Los puntos mínimos para los privilegios ya están decididos, no es algo que esté sujeto a la opinión de la comunidad, sin embargo, es posible hacer propuestas de cambios caso por caso.

Si la propuesta tiene como finalidad beneficiar únicamente  a SOES, el procedimiento es hacerla aquí con la etiqueta [característica-nueva](/questions/tagged/caracter%c3%adstica-nueva).

Si la propuesta tiene como finalidad o implica beneficiar a toda la red de sitios se debería hacer en https://meta.stackexchange.com con la etiqueta `feature-request`.

Me imagino que una propuesta de cambios en el requisito de reputación para un privilegio deberá ser revisado por el Community Team, cuyos miembros se indican en [Who are the Community Team, and what do they do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/289691).

<sup>La traducción está en [¿Quiénes forman el Community Team? ¿Qué hacen?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1670/65)</sup>

---

¿En qué me baso para decir que ya están decididos? Aunque los sitios varían los niveles de reputación requeridos por los privilegios durante la fase beta y la fase de sitio graduado a diferencia de la creación de nuevos sitios, temática de SOES, la elección de moderadores ♦, etiquetas, wikis de etiqueta, [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), sinónimos, traducciones, cerrar/abrir preguntas, ni SOES ni los sitios que conozco de SE tienen un hilo/proceso ni oficial ni oficializado para sugerir y votar los puntos de reputación requeridos por los privilegios de forma extensiva.

Encontré una propuesta más o menos así en Meta SE pero fue descartada porque la tasa costo/beneficio se consideró como muy baja.  Véase [Quantile based privilege limits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70586/289691).

---

**Ejemplos de SOES**

Aún no hay ejemplos, pero la siguiente búsqueda debería ayudar a encontrarlos en un futuro

[[privilegios][característica-nueva]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/privilegios+caracter%C3%ADstica-nueva)

**Ejemplos de Meta Stack Exchange**

- [Shouldn't a reputation points-less newbie at least be able to upvote a good answer to his/her own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1661/289691)
- [Rep for "view vote count" privilege should be lower (on meta)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97892/289691)
- [Reduce the reputation requirements for editing and approving edits during the very early beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116779/289691)
- [Opt in "mentor" privilege at 7.5k](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254205/289691)